# Take mean of more than one columns in pandas

Tags: pandas, mean

Below is my dataframe that I need to take average of cols within each group

```
data = [['Group 1',10,100],
['Group 1',20,80],
['Group 1',15,60],
['Group 1',10,120],
['Group 2',10,120],
['Group 2',20,130],
['Group 2',30,200],
['Group 2',40,250],
['Group 2',50,300]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Group','price','size'])
```

I would like to take the average of price and size within each group. So the desired output look like

```
Group     price_avg size_avg 
Group 1    13.75     90
Group 2    30        200
```

Thank you.

Comment: `df.groupby('Group').mean()` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df.groupby('Group').agg(
    price_avg=('price', 'mean'),
    size_avg=('size', 'mean')
)
```

```
Group   price_avg   size_avg
Group 1 13.75       90
Group 2 30.0        200
```

Comment: TypeError: aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'

Comment: Should've mentioned that it requires the latest version of pandas. Otherwise try: `df.groupby('Group').agg('mean').rename(columns={'price': 'price_avg', 'size': 'size_avg'})`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried .agg or .transform?

```
df.groupby('Group').agg(mean)
or 
df.groupby('Group').transform(mean, axis=1)
```